# Best way to create a connection class for mass multiple connections

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I would like some advice on how to go about creating a database connection class that is efficient for handling between 200 and 600 connections per second in PHP. Any advice about methods to use, or server settings would be appreciated.

Comment: This question is unsalvagable because a solution (in the form of a class) is proposed in the question that is not the solution. This is more a question of systems architecture that is beyond the scope of stackoverflow.

Comment: Would anyone suggest using persistent connections over standard?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a [max_connections](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections) that has to be set to cover the total number of connections. [back_log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_back_log). Backlog is only effective as the linux sysctl `net.core.somaxconn` (defaults to 128).

Thread cache is also important to consider to ensure threads aren't being created every connection.

Recommend reading through [mysql client connections](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/client-connections.html). Adjust references relevant to your MySQL version.

No PHP recommendations from me. https://dba.stackexchange.com/ is recommended for database questions, http://serverfault.com/ may give you hints for a lot of connections. Don't use a tiny VM server and expect massive performance.

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP standpoint there is nothing special to be done. Any class that is sanely designed would do. You only nave to make sure that a connection is done only once per script execution. If your code is the traditional PHP spaghetti, a singleton would do. For the Object-oriented code, however, consider using Dependency injection instead.

200 to 600 connections per second is not a big deal too. It wouldn't require as much concurrent connections if your database operations are fast. For example, if your PHP script works for 0.1 seconds, it will require a modest number of 60 concurrent connections, not a big deal.

Comment: The operations are very quick. Simple inserts with prepared statements. I've tried with a singleton connection, but over 200 concurrent requests cause it to time out. I've heard solutions outside php utilize a connection pool. I've achieved okay results using persistent connections but have also heard that is a bad idea. Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score -1):

Mysql default concurrent connection is 150. 
your limit is way above than that.
you will have to implement
thread cache
table cache
query cache

In PHP u will have to use singleton class to make connections, so that connections are reused. A small ex is

```
function connect()
{
   static $connection;
      if($connection == null)
      {
        $dsn = "mysql://{$username}:{$password}@{$hostName}/{$databaseName}";

            $connection = DB::connect($dsn);

            if (DB::isError($connection))
            {
                echo "db connect error";
                return FALSE;
            }  
      }
}
```

In the code, every call to connect() does not end up creating a new connection. A new connection is created only for the very first call to connect(), subsequent calls to connect() uses the same connection.